# Find an interval of definition for the differential equation $y^{\prime} = x^2(1+y^2)$ and $y = \tan(\tfrac{1}{3}x^3 + c)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am told to verify that the function $y = \tan(\tfrac{1}{3}x^3+c)$ satisfies the differential equation $y^{\prime} = x^2(1+y^2)$ *on some open interval* where $c$ is a real constant. It is straightforward to show that $y$ satisfies the given differential equation, so my question pertains to finding an appropriate interval of definition/validity/existence etc.

Let $I$ denote the interval of definition on which $y$ is defined. I know that $I$ must be constructed in such a way that $y$ and $y^{\prime}$ are continuous. Therefore,

$$\tfrac{1}{3}x^3+c \not \in \{\tfrac{2k+1}{2} \pi \, : \, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

But I'm having trouble defining $I$ in a "nice" and coherent way to express the above observation

Comment: I think what you have is as nice as one can expect...from that $\;x\notin\{\sqrt[3]{\frac32(2k+1)\pi +C}\;|\;k\in\Bbb Z\}\ldots\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio So it really doesn't matter if I reduced the expression $\tfrac{1}{3}x^3 + c$ to an expression of $x$ only?

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis of the problem is correct.

When they ask for the interval of definition they have to provide an initial condition.

For example in your problem if $y(0)=0$, $$ y = \tan(\tfrac{1}{3}x^3+c)$$ implies that $c=0$ therefore  $ y = \tan(\tfrac{1}{3}x^3)$

Now you solve     $-\pi /2<1/3x^3<\pi /2$ to find  the interval of definition associated to this particular initial condition.

Answer (score 0):

For given real $c$ and integer $n$, $\tan(x^3/3 + c)$ will satisfy the differential equation on the interval where $\left(n-\frac12\right) \pi < \frac{x^3}{3}+c < \left(n+\frac12\right)\pi$, i.e.  $((3n-3/2)\pi - c)^{1/3} < x < ((3n+3/2)\pi - c)^{1/3}$.